# How to select the first file input when there are multiple ones with the same name

Tags: javascript, forms, file

I am making a form where users have to add at least one picture, when the page loads there is one input given and the user can click "add another picture" which gives them another file input.

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/>
```

All of the file inputs will have the name: file[] 
Because I want the users to at least enter one file I need to check the first input with that name and check its value.
How can i select only the first one?

This is the code i tried but it didn't work:

```
if(document.getElementsByName("file")[0].value == 0 ){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing square bracket in the argument string.

```
document.getElementsByName("file[]")[0]
//                          ----^^----
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the id, because the document.getElementsByName return a array

> document.getElementById('file')